# plotly dash display graph_objects pie chart inside html elemet

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly.graph-objects

I am trying to display pie chart inside html div as below:

```
html.Div([
go.Figure(data=Piedata)
])
```

I got an error:

> “An object was provided as children instead of a component, string, or
> number (or list of those). Check the children property”

If I try to display the same chart in a separate file using `.show()` it works, but when I try to display it in the app.py file with another `html.div` components I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

Use dcc.Graph(figure=your_figure_name) instead

```
html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=your_figure_name)
])
```

Look at https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/graph for more details about its documentation